# Present $\Psi$ as linear equations in the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In the space of linear transformations $L(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^2)$ there is a subspace
$$\Psi = \{ \phi \in  L(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^2): \text{ker}(\phi) \supseteq \text{lin}((1,1,1)) \} $$
Describe $\Psi$ with linear equations in the standard basis of $L(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I am able to present $\Psi$ as a linear combination of matrices from the standard basis of $L(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^2)$.

$$
M(\phi)
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\left(
a_{11}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
+
a_{12}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
+ \dots +
a_{23}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\right)
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
How do I get a system of linear equations from this?

Comment: What is your expression of $\Psi$ as a linear combination of matrices from the standard basis?

Comment: You are almost done. Simply write out the last equation. Since $L(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^2)$ is six dimensional, and $\Psi$ is one dimensional, you only have to impose one linear equation for the basis $\{a_i\}_{i= 1, \cdots 6}$, which is exactly the one you wrote down.